# Array Arithmetic, Excel, Non-VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not looking for a VBA solution to this.
The goal is to find how many hours John has worked in a 12 month period, starting on 7/1/2015.
I have two worksheets. Worksheet one looks like the following:

```
Name   |     Date Start     | Total Hours
John   |     7/1/2015       |    Formula goes here
```

Worksheet two

```
   Date    |     John           |    Jane         | Joe
  7/1/2015 |      3             |    2            | 2.5
  7/2/2015 |      3             |    2.5          |  0
  rest of attendance data
```

The dates can go down as far as the spreadsheet will allow. What I'm looking to do is to keep the function in the worksheet formula. The formula I have now is:

```
=SUMIFS(Worksheet2!B:B, Worksheet2!$A:$A, ">="&Worksheet1!$B2, Worksheet2!$A:$A, "<="&EDATE(Worksheet1!$B2, 12))
```

If I did this through VBA, I could do something like:

```
Range("B"&2 & ":" & "B" & 1058476)
```

But I am looking for some way to look up what column the person, whos name is on sheet 1 in the row, what column their name occurs in sheet 2; then, sum up all the values in that column in sheet 2 that fall between the the 12 month time span, and put that number in worksheet 1 cell C2. I don't want to use Worksheet2!B:B.

Comment: Nevermind! I have answered this - something like: =SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(Attendance!$A$1, 0, 1, 368))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use Offset.

```
=SUMIFS(OFFSET(Worksheet2!A:A,0,MATCH(Worksheet1!$B1,Worksheet2!$A2:$A100,0)), Worksheet2!$A:$A, ">="&Worksheet1!$B2, Worksheet2!$A:$A, "<="&EDATE(Worksheet1!$B2, 12))
```

should fetch the correct column.